# 3 Months previous data by given date mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have fee records in my database table. I want to fetch 3 months back records of the fees in database. I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM fee_challans
    WHERE student_id = 630
    AND STATUS =  'un-paid'
    AND DATE_FORMAT( fee_date,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

This query that I searched and found on google.

Comment: So you can't figure ot hw to change this from 2 months to 3 months? #WhereDidWeFail

Comment: Do you want to fetch only the records from the exact month (3 month back) or from NOW() - 3 Month to NOW()?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to compare your column to something...

```
SELECT * FROM fee_challans
    WHERE student_id = 630
    AND STATUS =  'un-paid'
    AND fee_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
```

And if your `fee_date` column is of type `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`, `date_format()` is not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean? Explain your question better, please.

Comment: Actually I want to fetch data from the given date to previous three months, fee_date this is the column in my database in which date is located.

Comment: So want to fetch three months back data like if my date is 2013-05-03 i want to get all data on based on this date to previous three months.

Comment: Well, then replace `CURDATE()` with `'2013-05-03'`.

Comment: Serious question: Do you have data in your table which should be selected? Quite common "mistake"...

Comment: Second question: Is your fee_date column of type date, datetime or timestamp?

Comment: Then it would be best if you provided sample data and desired result. Otherwise we can't tell, what's wrong.

Comment: How may I provide sample data is there any place where I can upload screen shot?

Comment: Never use screenshot. Edit it as text into your question or use http://sqlfiddle.com